# Alternatives to the plank

Tags: exercise, injury

I have hurt my shoulder so for the next 2-4 weeks I have to be a little careful with my training. The daily running is properly OK as long as I keep away from the most challenging trail runs, but the daily dose of the plank has to be replaced for the duration with something a little more gentle.

But what are the good alternatives to the plank if it a part of a daily morning exercise?

Comment: Barbell front squat? The rack rests on the deltoids, but that might not actually hurt your "shoulder" depending on what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tonny, 
 
Sorry about the shoulder injury. There are *minor* alternatives to planks; however, they all involve shoulder usage. 
 
In my opinion, if you cannot perform plank *(an exercise that requires no movement)* due to shoulder issues, no other single exercise exists as a substitute. 
 
This [source](http://www.trihardist.com/2009/04/eight-great-alternatives-to-plank.html) highlights some exercises that can be done to replace planks; however, they still won't give as much benefits.

Comment: The problem is that the static press is on the exact ligaments that has been hurt. Thanks for the reference - I'll check it out soon.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some core workouts I can think of that shouldn't use the shoulder.

- Superman (without arms extended)
- Crunches
- Reverse Crunch
- Bicycles
- Side Crunch

Source: I hurt my shoulder back in January and did a lot of these instead of the plank family.

Comment: Unfortunately, only Spiderman uses the transverse abdominus, which is used in plank.  I guess this may be a useful suggestion, as whilst it does still use shoulder, there is less weight on it than plank

Comment: Add Leg Lifts & Flutter Kicks to this list